# Complex locus least value

Tags: complex-numbers

Complex number $z$ satisfies $|z+i|=1$, and complex number $w$ satisfies $\arg(w-2)$$ =$$ 3\pi\over4$. What is the least value of $|z-w|$?

I have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think at it as finding the closest points between a circle and a half-line in the complex plane.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it with algebra?

Comment: Sure, but it's a lot easier if you grasp the geometric intuition first.

Comment: I gave it a thought and understood that it’s between the circle and half line

Comment: The min value will be in the 4th quadrant

Comment: The $z$ point, yes, the $w$ point will be in the 1st quadrant. You can actually figure those two points on a hand-drawn sketch.

Comment: Hand drawn sketch can get messy how would I find it otherwise?

Comment: Once you found it the "*messy*" way, it should be easier to prove it algebraically, if you must. Maybe I am wrong, but at first sight this doesn't look like it was "arranged" for a pure, easy algebraical solution. You did not give much context about where the question came up, like algebra vs. calculus.

Comment: I understood that z is any complex number on the circle centred (0,-1) and w is any complex number on half line at an angle 3pi/4 the question is just asking the shortest distance between z and w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asks for the minimum distance $d=|z-w|$ between two points respectively on the circle $|z+i|=1$ and the half-line $\arg(z-2)=\frac{3 \pi}{4}\,$. Geometrically, it is obvious that the minimum distance is attained for the solid red segment drawn below, along the perpendicular from the center of the circle to the half-line.

[image]

By inspection, the endpoints of the segment are $z=\frac{3+i}{2}$ and $w=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}-i$, thus $d^2=\frac{11-6\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Algebraically, let $z=\cos(t)-i\,(1-\sin(t))$ and $w= 2-r+i\,r$ with $r \gt 0$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
d^2 &= (\cos(t)+r-2)^2 + (r+1-\sin(t))^2
\\ &= \underbrace{\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)}_{=\, 1}+2\left((r-2)\cos(t)-(r+1)\sin(t)\right)+(r-2)^2+(r+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

Using that $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a\cos\varphi-b\sin\varphi\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
d^2 &\ge 1 - 2 \sqrt{(r-2)^2+(r+1)^2} + (r-2)^2+(r+1)^2
\\ &= \left(\sqrt{(r-2)^2+(r+1)^2}-1\right)^2
\\ &= \left(\sqrt{2r^2-2r+5} - 1\right)^2
\\ &= \left(\sqrt{2\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{9}{2}}-1\right)^2
\\ & \ge \left(\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}-1\right)^2
\\ &= \frac{11-6\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align}
$$

The minimum distance is attained for $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$, which matches the geometric result.